# How to convert unicode text to this type

Tags: html, unicode, converters

I don't know type of this characters, I want to convert unicode characters to that to insert HTML.

```
Hay quá -> Hay qu&#225;
```

Because only this type display unicode in my website
Thanks very much!

Comment: The text representation should probably work too.  Are you perhaps missing a `<meta charset="utf-8">` tag at the top of `<head>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is NCR Decimal character, you can search with keyword "convert unicode to ncr decimal" on google to convert online.
such as: http://www.multi-converter.com
Good luck!